# Only get the value if a condition is true

Tags: c#, linq

I am checking to see if element1, element 2 or element 3 exists and then add them to finalData if they exist. However
if one of those dont exist or are not true then I just want to add the elements whose bool value is true! Below is my code

```
bool hasElement1 = (

                from Playlist in loaded.Descendants("Node")
                select Playlist.Descendants("Element1").Any()
                ).Single();

bool hasElement2 = (

                from Playlist in loaded.Descendants("Node")
                select Playlist.Descendants("Element2").Any()
                ).Single();

bool hasElement3 = (

                from Playlist in loaded.Descendants("Node")
                select Playlist.Descendants("Element2").Any()
                ).Single();

var finalData = from x in loaded.Descendants("Node")

                            select new
                            {

                                Element1 = x.Descendants("Element1").First().Value,
                                Element2 = x.Descendants("Element2").First().Value,
                Element3 = x.Descendants("Element3").First().Value,

                            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check if the elements exist before retrieving them. Try this:

```
var finalData = from x in loaded.Descendants("Node")
                select new
                {
                   Element1 = (string)x.Descendants("Element1").FirstOrDefault(),
                   Element2 = (string)x.Descendants("Element2").FirstOrDefault(),
                   Element3 = (string)x.Descendants("Element3").FirstOrDefault(),
                };
```